# rake assets:precompile Connection Refused EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-ec2, rake, asset-pipeline

So all of a sudden, when I attempt to execute rake assets:precompile, it has stopped working.

`$ RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace`

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
AssetSync: using /Users/paul/Documents/code/recruits/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "ec2-23-23-76-131.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (23.23.76.131) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5632?
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `new'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `connect'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:324:in `initialize'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
/Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
/Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__4045154819439227226__prepare__2403484953499382770__callbacks'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/paul/Documents/code/recruits/config/environment.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bi...]
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@recruits/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

I'm using Heroku Cedar, and I've tried connecting to Amazon via the aws-s3 gem and my credentials are working fine...

Here is my gemfile...

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.9'
gem 'best_in_place', '~> 2.1'
gem 'cancan', '~> 1.6'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.6'
gem 'carrierwave_direct'
gem 'country_select', '~> 1.1'
gem 'dalli', '~> 2.6'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'devise', '~> 2.2'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'feedzirra', '~> 0.2.0.rc2'
gem 'fog', '~> 1.10'
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'foreman', '~> 0.63'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 4.0'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'heroku-resque-auto-scale', git: 'git://github.com/prpetten/heroku-resque-auto-scale.git'
gem 'image_optim', '~> 0.8'
gem 'kaminari', '~> 0.14'
gem 'mechanize', '~> 2.6'
gem 'meta-tags', :require => 'meta_tags'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 3.5'
gem 'newrelic_rpm', '~> 3.6'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.5'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.13'
gem 'rack', '~> 1.4'
gem 'rakismet', '~> 1.3'
gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
gem 'resque', :require => 'resque/server'
gem 'resque-scheduler', require: 'resque_scheduler', git: 'git://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler'
gem 'rack-timeout', '~> 0.0'
gem 'rake', '~> 10.0'
gem 'rinku', :require => 'rails_rinku'
gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.13'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 2.1'
gem 'sitemap_generator'
gem 'twitter', '~> 4.6'
gem 'unicorn', '~> 4.6'

group :assets do
  gem 'asset_sync', '~> 0.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '>= 3.0'
  gem 'jquery_datepicker', '~> 0.4'
  gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.2'
  gem 'jquery-rails-cdn', '~> 0.4'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails', git: 'git://github.com/techbang/jquery-ui-rails.git'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails-cdn', '~> 0.1'
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '~> 2.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'better_errors', '~> 0.8'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', '~> 0.7'
  gem 'debugger', '~> 1.5'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.1'
  gem 'capybara-mechanize', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 0.9'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.2'
  gem 'fakeweb', '~> 1.3'
  gem 'guard', '~> 1.8'
  gem 'guard-bundler', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'guard-livereload', '~> 1.4'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 2.5'
  gem 'guard-spork', '~> 1.5'
  gem 'haml-rails', '~> 0.3'
  gem 'launchy', '~> 2.3'
  gem 'meta_request', '~> 0.2'
  gem 'multi_json', '~> 1.7'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spork', '~> 0.8'
  gem 'vcr', '~> 2.4'
end
```

It was working totally fine until yesterday, I can't seem to make heads or tails of this issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out this issue was caused by Heroku switching databases after my original database encountered an error.  This switch needed to be updated in my database.yml file.